# r: Reshape data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

[image]

How can I do this reshape of the data.frame so I can have a new column with the cell lines and another column for each gene without changing the rest

Comment: Read about transpose: `?t`

Answer (score 0):

Considering that `df` is the name of your dataframe, then:

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(t(df))[-1,]
colnames(df2) <- df$Geneid
```